# CakePHP allowing, denying access using Auth

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have a model 'events' that holds its own data + user id. How do I grant access only to the user to whom the event belongs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add a check at the beginning of your view method to see if the Authenticated user id matches that of the event. If not, redirect them back with an "access denied" flash message. For example, in your EventsController add:

```
public function view($event_id) {
    // Make sure the event exists at all
    if (!$this->Event->exists($event_id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('No such event.'));
    }

    // Get the event data
    $event = $this->Event->findById($event_id);

    // Match the authenticated user with the user_id of the event.
    if ($this->Auth->User('id') != $event['Event']['user_id']) {
        // No match, redirect the user back to the index action.
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('This is not your event!'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }

    /**
     * If this point is reached, the user is the owner of the event.
     * The rest of your logic goes below this point.
     */
}
```

Comment: That was just a perfect answer! Can the Auth component only return the id or any field of a User? I would like to allow the user whose role is admin to view all of the events as well?

Comment: @JohhnyP You can access any information of the authenticated user that is stored in your `users` table, so if the role is set in `role_id`, just check `$this->Auth->User('role_id')` to match your admin role id.